# passing different arguments to mp.Pool() for different processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, hpc

I am trying to parallelize a piece of code using the `multiprocessing` library, the outlines of which are as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
def stats(a,b,c,d,queue):
   t = time.time()
   x = stuff
   print(f'runs in {time.time() -t} seconds')
   queue.put(x)

def stats_wrapper(a,b,c,d):
   q = mp.Queue()
   # b here is a dictionary
   processes = [mp.Process(target = stats,args = (a,{b1:b[b1]},c,d,q) for b1 in b]
   for p in processes:
     p.start()
   results = []
   for p in processes:
     results.append(q.get())
   return(results)
```

The idea here is to parallelize the calculations in `stuff` by creating as many processes as there are key:value pairs in `b`,which can go upto 50. The speedup I'm getting is only about 20% as compared to the serial implementation.

I tried rewriting the `stats_wrapper` function with `mp.Pool` , but couldn't get the `apply.async` function to work with different `args` as I have created in `stats_wrapper` above.

Questions :-

1. How can I improve the `stats_wrapper` function to bring down the
   runtime further?
2. Is there a way to rewrite the `stats_wrapper` using `mp.Pool` function that can 
   accept a different value for parameter `b` in the `stats` function
   for different processes? Something like :

   ```
   def pool_stats_wrapper(a,b,c,d):
       q = mp.Queue
       pool = mp.Pool()

       pool.apply_async(stats,((a,{b1:b[b1},c,d) for b1 in b)) # Haven't figured this part yet
       pool.close()
       results = []
       for _ in len(b):
          results.append(q.get())
       return (results)
   ```

I'm running the code on an 8 core 16 GB machine if that helps.

Comment: How long does each single process take to complete when you use multiprocessing?

Comment: about 2 seconds as measured in the updated ```stats``` definition